# How do I hide a jButton after it has been clicked in a jPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

Can anyone help me with my issue? I can't seem to figure out how I can make a jButton hide after it has been clicked ONCE.

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   //The hide code would go here

}
```

Comment: I should think it's: `jButton1.setVisible(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just use implement interface actionListener to your class:

```
public class test implements ActionListener {
```

Next, add actionListener to your button:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

Last in the implemented actionPerformed method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   if(e.getSource.equals(button)) button.setVisible(false); //set's the buttons visibility to false.
}
```

**Edit: If you want to do it for one button click, in the actionPerformed method if statement you can also do: **

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   if(e.getSource.equals(button) && !once){ 
      button.setVisible(false);
      once = true; //once is a boolean which shows if the button has been clicked once
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for

```
jButton1.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.